# How to create the pin unpin effect like this website?

Tags: html, css, parallax

www.kennedyandoswald.com

When we open this website after the video div there is a effect of faces changes, I want to create the same effect of faces change in my website, how can I do this??
I have tried the pin unpin js and also some other short codes but it is just not happening.
Need some guidance to create the same efeect.

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest you to avoid posting websites here. Reason: Simple! Over time, these websites undergo change, making the question useless for future referrers. Posting and image or a code snippet is encouraged.

Comment: thanks. i will keep a check on this in future.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, this is known as "Parallax Scrolling". The way this sort of website tends to work is to listen to the scroll event and, based on the number of pixels down the page the user is, position the other elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to work with http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/ plugin, or find the other.